# Writing vba codes usinf the IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new with VBA. How do I write this VBA:

> If a cell starts with DY, then return NAS in another cell. If not
>   return NAI.

Comment: Why do you need VBA? A normal Excel formula does the trick?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because zero effort taken to solve problem by user.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this sample to your needs:

```
Sub simple()
    If Left([A1], 2) = "DY" Then
        [B1] = "NAS"
    Else
        [B1] = "NAI"
    End If
End Sub
```